# rails elasticsearch-model multiple params query

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, kaminari, elasticsearch-model

I want to run multiple params of search with elasticsearch-model gem like below. Before i used *gem tire* to search records using multiple params of queries.

My model:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
   indexes :id, type: 'integer'
   indexes :title
   indexes :author
   indexes :category
   indexes :price
  end

 def self.search(params)
  tire.search(load: true) do
    query do
      boolean do
       must { string params[:title] } if params[:title].present?
       must { string params[:author] } if params[:author].present?
       must { string params[:category] } if params[:category].present?
       should { range :price, { gte: params[:price_range_min], lte: 
       params[:price_range_max] } } if 
       params[:price_range_min].present? 
       && params[:price_range_max].present?
     end
    end
   end
 end

end
```

My controller:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @books = Book.search(params)
    @books = 
    Kaminari.paginate_array(@books).page(params[:page]).per(10)
   end
 end
```

I followed this documentation [elasticsearch-model](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-model/) but i am getting results only for two params of field.

Any help?

Comment: You've provided the code which is using `tire`. But the problem is with the code that is using elasticsearch-model, right?

Comment: i want to do the same operation with elasticsearch-model.